# Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. If every non-zero vector $v$ is an evector of $A$, prove that $A$ is a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'll start with the things i already know, I know that for a vector $v$ to be an evector of $A$, then the following must be true

$Av = \lambda v$  this is only true if and only if....

$(A - \lambda I)v = 0$

and i also know that a diagonal matrix is a matrix that has the following form..

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & 0 \\ 0 & x_2   \end{pmatrix}$$

($x_1$ and $x_2$ can be any number and can equal the same number as well)

i swear... i think the hardest part about these types of problem is knowing where to start... i think im too used to being told where to start by my professors.. which is a bad habit of mine...

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Suppose $A$ is not diagonal. Can you find a vector $v$ such that $Av \neq \lambda v$ ?

Comment: Pick your favorite matrix $A $ and compute $Ae_1$. Do you see a pattern?

Comment: In other words, $Ae_i = \lambda e_i$...

Comment: The word is *eigenvector*, not "evector" if you please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

For $k\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$kI_nv=kv$$

---

**I'm only showing $n=2$. Use the same idea for higher $n$**

Suppose $v=\binom{a}{b}$ and $A=\left(\begin{matrix}x_1&y_1\\y_2&x_2\end{matrix}\right)$.

We have 
\begin{align}
Av&=\lambda v\\
\left(\begin{matrix}x_1&y_1\\y_2&x_2\end{matrix}\right)\binom{a}{b}&=\lambda \binom{a}{b}\\
\binom{ax_1+by_1}{ay_2+bx_2}&=\binom{\lambda a}{\lambda b}
\end{align}

Hence, $$x_1=x_2=\lambda$$
and $$y_1=y_2=0$$

Comment: Should i use what you gave me as an identity or as an equation that i have to solve?

Comment: What if there are more than one eigevalue?

Comment: @Soon_to_be_code_master just a hint. You can't actually use it in the proof. But it's some idea you can bounce off.

Comment: I have a question, why did you determine that $x1$ = $x2$ = $\lambda$ and $y1$ = $y2$ = 0 ? i guess i understand that x1 and x2 can equal any number, but i dont understand why y1 and y2 are both equal to 0

Answer (score 2):

One needs to account for the possibility that there are different eigenvalues for different vectors.  We may do so as follows:

Note the following argument is quite general and applies to any linear operator on any vector space over any field, whether finite dimensional or not:

Since every non-zero vector $v$ is an eigenvector, each has an associated eigenvalue $\mu(v)$:

$Av = \mu(v) v; \tag 1$

now if $w$ is a vector linearly dependent upon $v$,

$w = av \tag 2$

for some scalar $a$, then

$\mu(w) w = Aw = A(av) = aAv = a\mu(v) v = \mu(v) (av) = \mu(v)w, \tag 3$

or

$(\mu(w) - \mu(v))w = 0; \tag 4$

since $w \ne 0$ this implies

$\mu(w) = \mu(v); \tag 5$

if, on the other hand, we choose $w \ne 0$ linearly independent from $v$, then

$\mu(v + w) v + \mu(v + w)w = \mu(v + w)(v + w)$
$= A(v + w) = Av + Aw = \mu(v) v + \mu(w) w; \tag 6$

comparing coefficients of $v$ and $w$ on each side yields

$\mu(v + w) = \mu(v) = \mu(w); \tag 7$

we thus see that in the event every non-zero vector is an eigenvector, all the eigenvalues are the same; for any $v$,

$Aw = \mu(v)w = \mu(v) I w, \tag 8$

which shows that

$A = \mu(v)I, \tag{9}$

a scalar multiple of the identity, a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I just like to highlight the hint from steven gregory and Andrés E. Caicedo:

If every vector is an eigenvector of $A$, so $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ are, where
$$
e_i = (0,0,\ldots,0,\underbrace{1}_{i.th~position},0,\ldots,0)^T
$$
for $i=1,\ldots,n$.

So there exists $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$such that $Ae_i=\lambda_ie_i$. And now compute directly what $Ae_i$ is and you will can deduce the form of $A$.

A little bit more precisely:

> If $$A=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n}\\a_{21} & a_{22} & \dots & a_{2n}\\\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \dots & a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$$ then $$Ae_1=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}\\a_{21}\\\vdots\\a_{n1}\end{pmatrix}$$. So if $Ae_1=\lambda_1e_1$, then $$\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}\\a_{21}\\\vdots\\a_{n1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1\\0\\\vdots\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$ So $a_{11}, a_{21},\ldots,a_{n1}$ are determined by this equation!

Answer (score 0):

Matrix multiplication is a continuous function on $\mathbf{R}^n\to \mathbf{R}^n$.
If every $v$ is an eigen vector then the corresponding  eigenvalue  should vary continously with $v\in \mathbf{R}^n$, denote it by $\lambda_v$.

For simplicity, let us restrict to the subset $S=\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)^T\in \mathbf{R}^n \mid \sum_ix_i^2=1\} $ which being closed and bounded a compact set, and is also connected.

So, $\lambda_v$ restricted to $v\in S$ is also a continuous real valued function, its image has to be an interval being the continuous image of a connected set, and has to be compact. So the image is a singleton, call it $\lambda.$

So all the eigenvalues are the same. That is given matrix is scalar multiplication by $\lambda$. In particular a diagonal matrix.

Comment: The notion of continuity is alien to the given problem. (There was no assumption about the coefficient field).

Comment: @WlodAA:  "alien" means totally strange and perhaps unrecognizable with what we know. By pretending real numbers have nothing to do with the problem we deny ourselves good intuition.  My method will not carry over to  fields of prime characteristic would be a valid criticism, I admit.  Solving a problem  in an intutitively accessible approach and then crticising and analysing the proof for its validity to other cases is a valuable process of learning mathematics. Training everyone  to think like Bourbaki is not something I follow while teaching.